# How to add two types of marker in the google Map

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to add two types of the marker in the google map first type will be draggable and another type is fixed in the google Map. Is it possible ?? Because in draggable marker I have to use `googleMaps.clear();` which is clearing all existing marker in the google maps. Thanks in advance for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally today I have solved this issue. By simple trick,

I gave marker name by

Marker marker = ........

and I have cleared the marker by `marker.clear();` which is draggable.